# Angular - Subgrupo de acordo com o id do grupo

Tags: angular

Preciso que seja gerado o subgrupo de acordo com o selecionado no grupo. Consegui ir até a apresentar o id que foi selecionado no html, não to conseguindo passar este valor para o getid.

Estou usando Angular 6 + primeNg

**component grupo**

```
  grupo: Group[];
  @Output() idSelecionado = new EventEmitter();
   ngOnInit() { this.getListGroup();}

// Busca todos os grupos já cadastrados
  getListGroup() {
    this.service.getAllGroup()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.grupo = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
  // retorna o id que foi selecionado na lista
  onRowSelect(event) {
   this.idSelecionado.emit(event.data.id);
  }
```

**Componente Subgrupo**

```
  subgrupo: Subgroup[];
    @Input() idGrupo: any;

   getIdGroup() {
        this.service.getIdSubgroup(this.idGrupo)
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.subgrupo = data;
          });
      }
```

**component do html pai**

```
  idGroup: any;
  @Output() idTest = new EventEmitter();

  aoSelecionar(id) {
   this.idGroup = id;
    console.log(`O componente classificationn escutou o id: ${id}` );
  }
```

**html que está apresentando os outros**

```
  <div class="ui-g-6">
        <app-classification-group-form></app-classification-group-form>
        <app-classification-group-list (idSelecionado)='aoSelecionar($event)'></app-classification-group-list>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-6">

        <app-classification-subgroup-form></app-classification-subgroup-form>
        <app-classification-subgroup-list ></app-classification-subgroup-list>
       Escutando {{idGroup}}
    </div>
```

[image: Tela de visualização do grupo e subgrupo]

Comment: `<app-classification-subgroup-list [idGrupo]="idGroup" ></app-classification-subgroup-list>` Tenta fazer assim...

Comment: @LucasBrogni nada aconteceu. Mas percebi uma coisa. Vamos dizer que o id está indo, Como eu chamo o getIdGroup?

Comment: Existem algumas formas, você pode utilizar o ngOnChanges e chamar dentro dele, pode chamar no ngOnInit, pode dar um subscribe no event.

Comment: @LucasBrogni vlw deu certo aqui. Não conhecia esse ngOnChenges, fui pesquisar agora, testei e funciou.

Esse video do YT explica bem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7heex6vqUM

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta, ai você marca como concluído.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<app-classification-subgroup-list [idGrupo]="idGroup" ></app-classification-subgroup-list>` Tenta fazer assim... para passar o id para o subgrupo e utilize o `ngOnChanges` para chamar o método.